# What does the error 'IndentationError: expected an indented block in python' mean?

Tags: python

Consider following short Python program:

```
i= 21;
j= 23;
print (i);
if i>j :
print ('greater')
else :
print 'lesser'
```

It is giving the error

> IndentationError: expected an indented block

What is the cause of this error? (I want to understand it better as I am new to Python.)

Comment: This is really basic... Even though I don't do python I know identation defines blocks of statements. And the error message can't be more clear...

Comment: i have just started learning python and i can understand the error message, i was actually wondering that where i was wrong.. because if u see my code, i have statements after if-else clause.. but still i was getting that error. thats why i asked this question, may b a stupid one..the comment from @csmith has made it all clear. please dont discourage anyone from asking a question and learning from the answers..i know its basic and please note that  if uor basic is not clear then u cant write the complex codes, so to clear the basics is necessary..

Comment: Along with the error message, it says the line of code that has the problem.  The easiest thing to do is look at that line of code and think about why it might not have the right indentation.

Comment: @SethMMorton :: actually i was unaware of the fact that "Indents should be 4 spaces (tabs also work)", as explained by CSmith..

Comment: Technically, you just need to indent consistently. 4 spaces is only a guideline. Having said that, you should always use 4 spaces for indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to indent statements that are intended to be in `if-else` blocks:

```
i = 21
j = 23
print (i)

if i > j:
    print('greater')
else:
    print('lesser')
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you have a colon, you follow it with an indented block of text. Everything in that block applies to the thing with the colon (which could be a function that you're defining, an if-statement, for-loop, etc). Indents should be 4 spaces (tabs also work).

Also, you don't need semicolons at the end of each line.

Example:

```
def function(parameter):
    block line 1
    block line 2

print function(argument)
```

Comment: From my recollection PEP 8 discourages the use of tabs, partially because they lead to horrible errors if some lines use spaces and some tabs.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 :: then is it ok to use 4 spaces instead of tabs??

Comment: Yes, 4 spaces is the preferred method. Here's the style relevant section of the style guide:
http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces

Comment: Any good editor will have a setting to insert 4-spaces when you press tab.